# Using parameter in unix function

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I want to run a script using function. Script runs fine as is but want to run using function and pass something as arg

```
#! /bin/ksh
#
#       profile.ksh
#
#       sample Korn shell profileument. Example:

build(){
return /home/$1/script.sh;
}
```

However when I do something like:

$build 09272018

I get below error:

ksh: /home/09272018/script.sh: bad number

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Have tried various options without much luck.

Thank you!

Comment: Try [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net). It autodetects [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2152) with a faster round-trip time than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return arbitrary values from a shell function, only integers (usually between 0 and 255). Instead, you either write the "return value" to standard output:

```
$ build () { echo /home/$1/script.sh; }
$ script_name=$(build 09272018)
$ echo "$script_name"
/home/09272018/script.sh
```

or you set a global variable.

```
$ build () { script_name=/home/$1/script.sh; }
$ build 09272018
$ echo "$script_name"
/home/09272018/script.sh
```

(In any case, the value returned by `return` should be an exit status, where 0 indicates the function succeeded, and a non-zero value indicates it failed in some way. It should never be used to return data.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a different subdirectories, each with a script.sh.
Something like `${HOME}/version0_1/script.sh`,`${HOME}/johndoe/script.sh`, `${HOME}/version1_0/script.sh`.
Now you want to run the correct script using a parameter.
You can use `source` (that can be abbreviated with a dot `.`).
When you only need to call one script the parameter is fine, when you need to call a lot others, consider a variable.

## Just one call

```
build(){
   source ${HOME}/"$1"/script.sh;
}
build version1_0
```

Or

```
# When you need the parameter in other call to
build(){
   source ${HOME}/"${buildversion}"/script.sh;
}
buildversion="version1_0"
```

You might note that I placed the version in double quotes. Perhaps somebody makes a subdir with a space like `${HOME}/version0.2 beta 3/script.sh`. I should place `${HOME}` in quotes too, but I think your system admin won't put a space in your homedir.